# Extract part of HTML in C/Objective-C

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xml, libxml2

I need to extract the detail content of a website while preserve all formatting of the division. The section I wish to extract is:

```
...
<div class="detailContent"><p>
<P dir=ltr><STRONG>Hinweis</strong>: Auf ... </p>
</div> 
...
```

My current solution is to use HTMLParser from libxml2 and xpath to find the nodes and walk through all the nodes to reconstruct this piece of HTML. This is a long an complicated code.

I' just wondering if there is an easier solution to extract part of HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you just want to pull out the div that is of class "DetailContent"?  I am not clear if you are asking about detailed content or the thing of that name.

Comment: Hi,

Yes. Just the div of class "DetailContent"

Comment: I was about to say: if you're using Objective C, you should try NSXML* classes, but then I noticed the iPhone tag. 
I haven't tried this myself, but it might be worth a try: KISSXML: 
http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/09/nsxml-on-iphone.html
http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Javascript solution: `document.getElementsByClassName("detailContent")`

Combine that with UIWebView's support for running Javascript and you might have a more concise solution.