# How to get a part of html file?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, parsing, xpath

I just want to get a part of an website within all the html-tags:

```
<table></table>
...
<div><font>some <b>kind</b> of <i>individual</i> text I need</font></div>
...
<div>other things I don't need</div>

-> I only want this: <font>some <b>kind</b> of <i>individual</i> text I need</font>
```

My goal is it to display this part with bold tags and images in a UIWebView. I've tried some XPath parser but these skipped the tags which I wanted to display in the web view.
On Stackoverflow I found a solution with java script: [extract-part-of-html-in-c-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045592/extract-part-of-html-in-c-objective-c) but I don't know how this could help me in my ios application

Hopefully someone can help me

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple XPath one-liner expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may find this useful:**  (see the Demo inside this article)

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Its almost everything that you need, except the "make tags bold" part

update: includes getting content from separate url

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get("http://www.website_i_need_to_parce.com", function(data){

  /// work with "data" variable as you work with "document"

  var htmlStr = data.html().find('#someDiv');

});
```

After this call - htmlStr will contain contents of the div with id="someDiv". If you need to paste these contents as html - use:

```
  $('#div_on_my_site_where_I_Want_to_paste_code').text(htmlStr);
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't written it above:
I don't have the permission to edit the html files, my task is it to parse the html file.

Comment: `.text()` will convert all the `>` and `<` tags to `&gt;` and `&lt;`. You want to use `.html()`.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: thats what he wants, "My goal is it to display this part with bold tags and images", i.e. to printout the code.  That can be done by .text(), not .html.
Also $.get wont work cross-domain though...

Answer (score 0):

**Supposing the context node is the parent of the `div` and the `div` is the first `div` child of the context node (You haven't provide the complete source XML !!!), this XPath expression selects the wanted nodes**:

```
div[1]/node()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/t">
     <xsl:copy-of select="div[1]/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped into a single top node to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <table></table>
    ...    
    <div>
        <font>some 
            <b>kind</b> of 
            <i>individual</i> text I need
        </font>
    </div>
     ...    
    <div>other things I don't need</div>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<font>some 
            <b>kind</b> of 
            <i>individual</i> text I need
        </font>
```

**Explanation**: The XPath expression above selects all children nodes of the first `div` child of the context node. This is exactly what is wanted: all children of the `div` element but excluding the `div` element itself.